# Understanding context switching in Spring cloud stream+AMQP

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-amqp

We are using **spring-integration-amqp-4.3.10.RELEASE,spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.RELEASE and spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit** in our project.We tried to accomplish **graceful shutdown** of our microservices by having `shutdown-timeout` placed in our inbound-channel-adapter.

**scenario**:

1. We are able to acheive graceful shutdown only for microservices without spring-cloud-stream.

   - we analysed it to be running in same listener thread, so it is getting terminating as expected.
2. When we try terminating the microservice(having spring-cloud-stream + AMQP)

   - We are not sure whether thread shifting is happening here, if it is happening ,how to implement shut down in such case.

Could you suggest us the way to overcome this second scenario??

Comment: can you please clarify _. . .and waiting for the workers to finish. . ._. Is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: have modified the question now.

Comment: There is no "thread shifting" - the service runs on the container thread; there should be no difference to a native Spring AMQP app.